# Python: Increment / Decrement a global variable (or alternative method)

Tags: python, global-variables, increment, decrement

These are two functions in a module I have written:

```
def start():
    numberstr = raw_input("Enter a number to start ")
    global number
    number = int(numberstr)
    readline("data.csv", number)
    control()

def control():
    operation = raw_input("Repeat (R), Next (N), or Previous (P) ")
    if operation == "R":
        readline("data.csv", number)
        control()
    elif operation == "N":
        readline("data.csv", number + 1)
        control()
    elif operation == "P":
        readline("data.csv", number - 1)
        control()
    else:
        print "Incorrect command"
        control()

start()
```

I am looking to have it prompt for an initial number, run the readline function and then the control function. The control function should start with that initial number and then be able to increment/decrement it as it prompts after each time the readline function is run.

The actual behavior is that it will increment once and then remain the same. The previous control is less predictable; I am not sure what is happening there.

I have read to avoid global variables, and I feel that it may be the root of the issue. I am unsure on how to implement the alternatives.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Pretty sure you just need to declare `global number` outside both functions, as well as inside each of them.

Comment: Actually it looks like you may not have to declare it outside of both, just inside both.

Comment: You don't need to edit your question with the answer you chose.

Comment: Inbar, I know, but I did here because I had to make a few changes for it to work and posted for other people's benefit. Do you feel that it adds unnecessary clutter?

Comment: Most assuredly. Take a queue from other questions/answers on this site to get a feel for how we do things here. You could also benefit from some Python tutorials, it is especially cruel to modify my proposed solution to the point where it is unrecognizable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def operate():
    number = input("Enter a number to start: ")
    while True:
        readline("data.csv", number)
        op = raw_input("Repeat (R), Next (N), Previous (P), or Quit (Q) ")
        if op == "R": pass
        elif op == "N": number += 1
        elif op == "P": number -= 1
        elif op == "Q": break
        else: raise Exception("Incorrect command")

operate()
```

This keeps it local, no need for globals, and it puts it into a loop which should reduce overhead. I also added a `Quit` option.

Comment: `numbers += 1` is the same as writing `numbers = numbers + 1` . You should accept the answer that you use.

Comment: Thank you for the update. This version of the function is very elegant. I have added .upper() after the raw_input so it can take in lower case letters too. Now I will work on exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but why not pass it as an argument?

Like this:

```
def start():
    numberstr = raw_input("Enter a number to start ")
    number = int(numberstr)
    readline("data.csv", number)
    control(number)

def control(number):
    operation = raw_input("Repeat (R), Next (N), or Previous (P) ")
    if operation == "R":
        readline("data.csv", number)
        control(number)
    elif operation == "N":
        number +=1
        readline("data.csv", number)
        control(number)
    elif operation == "P":
        number -=1
        readline("data.csv", number)
        control(number)
    else:
        print "Incorrect command"
        control(number)
start()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Still way less "messy" than using a global.

Comment: Thank you, that was very simple! I'll post my final working code.

Comment: recursion isn't necessary here but it is another alternative to using a while loop. should also add a 'Q' option to exit out of this otherwise it will run forever. You can also change `raw_input` to `input()` which takes an int value and eliminates the need for line 3